# import AVKit - no such module on tvOS, possible for iOS/multiplatform though

Tags: xcode, importerror, tvos, avkit

When starting a new tvOS project and try to import AVKit it says no such module available.

[image: No such module]

[image: Basic project settings]

I add them on Frameworks, Libraries and Content - still nothing.

[image: Print Screen of project settings]

Double checked if they are in BuildPhases - Link Binary with Libraries

[image: Build Phases]

Cleaned build folder and Derived Data. Nothing Worked. According to Apple's documentation it is supposed to be available for TVOS, but I simply cannot get it to be available.

When I start a new multiplatform or iOS project it is possible to import it, just not for tvOS, don't know what to do. Didn't have to add any framework manually, simply worked.

[image: No issues when starting a new ios project]

[image: Project settings ios]

Answer (score 0):

had to install a previous version 14.3.0 and rename it to 14__3_0(simply uninstalling current one and installing a previous one didn't work) and having two versions of Xcode did the trick.